# Локальные переменные и потоки

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что происходит "под капотом" у следующего кода:

```
    public void incrementSharedAtomic() throws InterruptedException {
        AtomicInteger sharedAtomic = new AtomicInteger(0);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            sharedAtomic.incrementAndGet();
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            sharedAtomic.incrementAndGet();
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Thread: result " + sharedAtomic.get());
        
        //output "Thread: result 2"
    }
```

Я читала, что у каждого потока свои копии локальных переменных, а в методе у нас переменные локальные, поэтому у меня получаются следующие рассуждения:

1. Каждый поток (`thread1` и `thread2`) получает свою копию `sharedAtomic`.
2. `AtomicInteger` является ссылочным типом и хранится в куче, поэтому потоки получают не копию самого объекта, а копию его ссылки на объект в куче.
3. Обе копии ссылки ссылаются на один и тот же объект в куче, поэтому `incrementAndGet()` изменяет значение у объекта в куче

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильны ли рассуждения?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что значение `sharedAtomic` будет видно обоим потокам (как если бы это было поле класса или поле с класса с `volatile`) и если выполнить по 10000 вызовов в каждом потоке, то итоговое значение будет 20000?

Comment: Да. А почему бы вам просто это не проверить?

Comment: @Saturn1401, проверить, что получится 20000? Я проверяла, но как говорила моя преподавательница по матану: "Если пять школьников пришли в школу со сменкой, означает ли это, что все школьники придут со сменкой?". Так и тут, запустив несколько раз,я  могу получить 20000, но это может означать лишь стечение обстоятельств. Поэтому и хотела разобраться, что именно происходит на уровне теории

Comment: Ну если что-то выглядит, пахнет и по вкусу пирожок, то это пирожок. Все-таки java надежный язык. Хотя проверки лишними не бывают, но вряд ли вы будете для проверки каждого класса  вопрос составлять

Answer (score 1):

Да, все правильно, но стоит упомянуть еще пару моментов. В принципе вы их и так рассмотрите при дальнейшем изучении многопоточности и как с ними бороться, можно не вчитываться особо, но на всякий случай пусть будут.

1. Типы копируются, но так же стоит иметь ввиду, что Java накладывает ограничения. Изначальная переменная используемая в lambda должна быть неизменяемая в дальнейшем.

Изменение ссылки приведет к ошибке, IDE такие моменты подсвечивает.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Food food = new Food();

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        food.setType(1);

        // Error: Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final
        // food = new Food();
    });

    // Error: Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final
    // food = new Food();
}
```

Но если исходную переменную нужно будет изменить вне lambda функции, можно скопировать ссылку в другую переменную и использовать эту новую переменную в потоках.

2. Класс AtomicInteger обеспечивает внутри атомарность операции.

При его использовании вы получите спокойно 20000. Если использовать volatile или просто обычный объект как в примере выше, то при определенных стечениях обстоятельств вы получите неверные результаты.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
    food.setPrice(food.getPrice() + 20);
});
```

В примере выше, если вызывается много потоков, то один может считать цену (допустим 100) и не успеть её обновить. Второй поток вклинится в код и считает "старую цену" (опять 100). В итоге вы получите не 140, а 120 из-за этого. Поэтому с многопоточностью стоит быть внимательным.

Comment: Java не запрещает ее изменять, просто поток после запуска не видит этих переменных

Comment: А по пункту 2 достаточно синхронизировать метод

Comment: @Saturn1401, компилятор явно выводит ошибку приведенную в примере в комментарии при попытке компиляции, даже если без IDE использовать javac. А по второму я так и написал "рассмотрите при дальнейшем изучении многопоточности и как с ними бороться".

Comment: Компилятор говорит что переменная должна быть окончательной

Comment: @Saturn1401 Так и в чем проблема? Можно чуть подробнее, пока я не понимаю вашей мысли.

Comment: Ну вы написала что Java(вероятно jvm) запрещает изменять, он не запрещает, а буквально не может ее изменить

Comment: @Saturn1401, немного сложнее, эти же запреты при должном старании можно обойти в Kotlin или Scala, которые работают на той же JVM, все-таки эту ошибку выдает анализатор. Хотя тоже не без оговорок, учитывая как это делают компиляторы. Если так будет лучше, то изменил формулировку на "ограничения", как это прямо и описано в спецификации `15.27.2. Lambda Body`. Может это будет меньше сбивать с толку.